# Why would the lumberg gem 4.1.0 have explicit runtime dependencies without a lumberg.gemspec file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

ruby 2.7.6

On rubygems.org, the lumberg 4.1.0 gem is listed as having the following dependencies:

```
RUNTIME DEPENDENCIES (3):
faraday ~> 0.9.0
faraday_middleware ~> 0.9.0
json >= 1.8.2
```

Looking at the gem source, I note there is no lumberg.gemspec file specifying these dependencies so I am curious as to how it acquired those particular dependencies, especially when the installed faraday gem is at 2.7.10.

I have another gem also dependent on faraday (~> 2.5) resulting in bundler being unable to find compatible versions for gem faraday.

Solving this bundler resolver conundrum relies on understanding how lumberg set its runtime dependencies and fixing that.

But how?

Responding to BroiSatse OOI comment.

I looked in the gems project directory as follows:

```
12:29:18 ✔ cb:(master) sb$ cd `bundle show lumberg`
direnv: loading ~/.envrc
direnv: export ~PATH
12:29:27 ✔ cb: lumberg-4.1.0$ ll
total 88
drwxrwxr-x    4 cb cb  4096 Aug  5 11:03 ./
drwxrwxr-x 1279 cb cb 49152 Aug  7 12:29 ../
-rw-rw-r--    1 cb cb    91 Aug  5 11:03 Gemfile
drwxrwxr-x    3 cb cb  4096 Aug  5 11:03 lib/
-rw-rw-r--    1 cb cb  1057 Aug  5 11:03 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--    1 cb cb  1276 Aug  5 11:03 Rakefile
-rw-rw-r--    1 cb cb 10380 Aug  5 11:03 README.md
drwxrwxr-x    8 cb cb  4096 Aug  5 11:03 spec/
12:29:29 ✔ cb: lumberg-4.1.0$ find . -name '*.gemspec'
12:30:00 ✔ cb: lumberg-4.1.0$
```

No gemspec file. Not sure how to handle the seemingly impossible resolver conflict without it.

Comment: I probably miss something but isn‘t it defined here in the gemspec? https://github.com/envato-archive/lumberg/blob/master/lumberg.gemspec

Comment: OOI - where did you look at the source?